# How could I display a time difference in python in total "hours:minutes:seconds"?

Tags: python, time, difference

In Python, I retrieved a start time and end time using `datetime.datetime.now()`.  I would like to round any microseconds to the nearest second and convert days into hours.  The final displayed format of the time difference should be `"hours:minutes:seconds"`.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Subtracting two `datetime`s will give you a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), it's pretty easy given the attributes on that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to format a `timedelta` object as you wish, so you have to do the calculations by yourself:

```
    delta = end - start
    seconds = int(round(delta.total_seconds()))
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    print("{:d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(hours, minutes, seconds))
```